# Electric dryer plug

Tags: electrical, dryer

[image]How do I connect a dryer with a four prong plug to a three prong socket for a Maytag electric dryer?

Is there a converter plug that goes from 4 prong to 3 prong outlet?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the outlet box for the dryer outlet?

Comment: Can you turn the breaker off, take the front cover off the outlet (remove the screw between the prongs), and post a photo of the insides please?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions:

- Change the receptacle

The existing receptacle (NEMA 10-30) can be replaced with a new 4-wire receptacle (NEMA 14-30). The catch is that you need to add a **ground wire** to do this. If the existing wiring is in metal conduit then may be able to use that as a ground path. If the dryer receptacle is in the same room as your main breaker panel then it is easy enough to run a new cable. But if it is "elsewhere" then it may be a bit more complicated. You **may** be able to retrofit a ground wire to solve the problem.

- Change the plug

Most dryers can be adapted to a 3-wire cable/plug by replacing the cable/plug and connecting neutral and ground. **However, this is not as safe as changing the receptacle and not recommended.** There are certain fault scenarios where this could leave you vulnerable to dangerous voltage that would not happen with the new 4-wire receptacle.

For some more info, take a look at:

[Dryer Outlet - 4 prong to 3 prong](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116738/dryer-outlet-4-prong-to-3-prong/116740#116740)

[Issues with 4 Prong to 3 Prong Conversion](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/issues-with-4-prong-to-3-prong-conversion/143853#143853)

Comment: Rather than answering questions repeatedly, just do the close vote.

Comment: @isherwood I hear you. Find an exact duplicate. The one you linked to (which is one of the ones I linked to for more info.) is "3 prong dryer, 4 prong socket". This question is the reverse "4 prong dryer, 3 prong socket". The other one I linked is a bit more complicated because it was in a rental and 4-prong cord already removed. If you can find an exact duplicate (there very likely is one *somewhere*) then I'll agree with you.